# first paragraph entry

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

In EE2.9 (can go up) is it possible to target the first paragraph of text in a channel entry?
I want to add a class only to this first paragraph for a CSS3 drop cap to the text.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Justin

Comment: So it would be a text area and /* p:first-child:first-letter { float: left; color: #903; font-size: 75px; line-height */ would a sample of the CSS. The CSS isn't the problem it's figuring out the EE side, but I guess what your saying is there is no EE side to this.

Comment: Without wrapping your EE variable tag in a custom plugin that parses the text identifying the first paragraph tag in PHP and adding the relevant class, there's no way to do it (as @jrothafer has mentioned). But depending on how your text held in ExpressionEngine, you could view source and add the class in the wysiwyg editor, or if using a third-party fieldtype like Wygwam, you can add classes to specific paragraphs through styles.

Comment: Unless there was a parameter available for the channel entry then it is much more of the CSS question as I'm trying to highlight the first three words of a paragraph without having to do any manual formatting because of the sheer number of pages.specifically I want to capitalize the first three words which I have almost have a decent solution in place already, but the contributions here have been very helpful. Just hoping there was something simpler In EE to trigger that CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what your output field is. Is it a text area? A rich text area? WYGWAM field? Answer that question and I can hone in. But here is an example CSS selector:

```
.channel-entries .field-id-666 p:first-of-type {

    /* your CSS rules go here */

}
```

Note that I don't actually know the class names off the top of my head, but a `:first-of-type` selector sounds like your answer.

Also note this isn't an EE related question really, but it's *just* close enough to not flag :P

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately there is no multi-word CSS selector that I'm aware so it would require jQuery too. Best bet seems to be to do it manually with a b or a strong tag.